# The proof of P2b in Paxos made simple

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

I am reading *[Paxos Made Simple](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf)*. I am quite confused about the proof of P2b. It said

> We would make the proof easier by using induction on n, so we can prove that proposal number n has value v under the additional assumption that every proposal issued with a number in m..(n - 1) has value v.

How can he add the **additional assumption**? Is it reasonable? In reality, proposal numbered in m..(n - 1) can have value other than v, isn't it?

I am really confused about that, please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* I have had a similar question about the correctness proof of Paxos and Fast Paxos before and [posted it here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/25851/12739). Wish the excellent answer to it be helpful to you.

---

*A few words about this paper:*

Leslie Lamport has his own, very impressive writing style. He is not satisfied with the common pattern of stating a theorem, proving it, moving on to another theorem, and so on. He is good at demonstrating the way how to solve a problem. In his paper, you will see that proof does not *follow* a theorem; instead, it *comes along with* a theorem. The paper "Paxos Made Simple" is a typical example of this style.

---

*About your questions:*

> *Your question (1):* How can he add the additional assumption? Is it reasonable?

Leslie Lamport is using [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction). The goal here is to prove

> $P2^{b}:$ If a proposal with value $v$ i chosen (say, with number $m$), then every higher-numbered proposal issued by any proposer has value $v$.

We apply strong induction to natural number $\mathbb{N}$. I summarize the proof as follows and explain it later.

- The base case is "some proposal with number $m$ and value $v$ is chosen".
- The *strong* induction hypothesis is "every proposal issued with a number in $m .. (n-1)$ has value $v$".
- **The induction step to prove $P2^{b}$**: Combining the premise of "$m$ is chosen (with value $v$)" with the above induction hypothesis, we get (for reference, I call it $C$-condition):

> *$C$-condition:* Every acceptor in $C$ (defined in the paper) has accepted a proposal with number in $m .. (n-1)$, and every proposal with number in $m .. (n-1)$ accepted by any acceptor has value $v$.

Now, Lamport introduces $P2^{c}$, which, along with the above $C$-condition, is sufficient for $P2^{b}$.

You can think of this induction process step by step:

1. The base case $m$ is trivially valid.
2. Given that step 1 is valid, the argument in "**The induction step**" above (of course with $P2^{C}$) shows that the proposals numbered $m+1$ has value $v$.
3. Given both step 1 and step 2 are valid, the same argument shows that the proposals numbered $m + 2$ has value $v$.
4. And so on.

This also answers your second question.

> *Your question (2):* In reality, proposal numbered in $m..(n - 1)$ can have value other than v, isn't it?

No, it isn't. The Paxos algorithm guarantees that all the proposals with larger numbers than $m$ must have value $v$, given that $m$ is chosen with value $v$.

Comment: Now I understand the **additional assumption** comes from strong induction. But I still have many questions.  1)Why you say the base case P(m) is trivial? Can you make it clear a bit? For me, If P(m) holds, then when proposal m is chosen, a higher-numbered proposal, say m+1, issued by other proposer must also has value v. But I can't figure it out. Unless on your strong induction, proposal m..n-1 has value v, so P(m) is true. But I think we should make strong induction after we have checked the base case P(m) is true.

Comment: 2) The inference of *C-condition* is the most confusing. On my view, you showed that the *C-condition* follows by just replace **m** with **m..(n-1)**, isn't it? If it is, I can't bridge the gap from m to m..(n-1) on my mind.