# Paxos made simple, invariant P2c

Tags: ds.algorithms, dc.distributed-comp, proofs

I am reading 
Leslie Lamport's [Paxos Made Simple](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf) paper.

Can someone explain why $P2^c$ implies $P2^b$?

> $P2^b$ If a proposal with value $v$ is chosen, 
>   then every higher-numbered proposal issued by any proposer has value $v$.
>
> $P2^c$ For any $v$ and $n$, 
>   if a proposal with value $v$ and number $n$ is issued,
>   then there is a set $S$ 
>   consisting of a majority of acceptors such that either
>
> 1. no acceptor in $S$ has accepted any proposal numbered less than $n$, or
> 2. $v$ is the value of the highest-numbered proposal among
>      all proposals numbered less than $n$ accepted by the acceptors in $S$.

Answer (score 2):

We prove it ($P2^c \implies P2^b$) by [strong induction (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction). This proof has actually been given in the "Paxos Made Simple" paper (see the arguments between $P2^b$ and $P2^c$). I re-organize it in the order of "what we know, what we want to prove, and how to prove". Hope it helps.

---

***What we know:***

*Base case:* Some proposal with number $m$ and value $v$ is chosen.

*Inductive assumption:* Every proposal issued with a number in $m \ldots (n-1)$ has value $v$.

*The chosen rule of a proposal:* For the proposal number $m$ to be chosen, there must be some set $C$ consisting of a majority of acceptors such that every acceptor in $C$ accepted it.

*The issue rule of a proposal:* It is the existence of a set $S$ such that $P2^c (1)$ + $P2^c (2)$.

***What we want to prove is:***

*Goal:* Any proposal issued with number $n > m$ also have value $v$.

---

***Proof:***

Combining "base case" and "chosen-rule" with "inductive assumption", we obtain:
***The $C$-condition:*** Every acceptor in $C$ has accepted a proposal with number in $m \ldots (n-1)$ (*Note:* because at least each of them has accepted a proposal with number $m$),
and every proposal with number in $m \ldots (n-1)$ accepted by any acceptor has value $v$ (*Note:* due to the inductive assumption and the fact that a proposal must be issued by a proposer before it can be accepted by an acceptor).

Now consider the set $S$ in $P2^c$ which consists of a majority of acceptors. Because $S \cap C \neq \emptyset$, $P2^c(1)$ cannot happen. Then $P2^c(2)$ must be true. $P2^c(2)$ is actually the "value-issued rule": the value $v'$ of the proposal with number $n$ is the value of the highest-numbered proposal among all proposals numbered less than $n$ accepted by the acceptors in $S$, therefore $v' = v$ because of the $C$-condition.

---

Related posts:

- [The proof of P2b in Paxos made simple@cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/27391/12739)
- [Correctness proofs of classic Paxos and Fast Paxos@cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/25851/12739).